# d3.js How to not graph values outside of range?

Tags: json, graph, d3.js

I have a multi-bar graph with 7 different bar listings. Dates are on the x axis and decimal values are on the y axis. Some of these listings have empty strings ("") for their decimal values and they are graphed as 0.000. I don't want these to show up at all. I tried using chart.yDomain.([0, 3]); and setting the empty values to -1 and they don't show up on the graph, but the spacing between the bars is the same as if they were graphed.

I also tried not putting empty value pairs into the graph datum array, but that messed up the date sorting since not every listing has a value for each date.

Here's an example of the JSON data I am using for the graphing:

```
"x_data":["08\/15\/13","11\/11\/13","11\/13\/13","11\/14\/13","11\/18\/13","11\/19\/13","11\/20\/13","11\/25\/13","12\/05\/13","12\/09\/13","12\/11\/13","12\/12\/13"],
"y_data":[[["","","","","","","",0.875,"",0.41,"",""]],[["","","","","","","","",0.285,"",0.92,""]],[["",0.203,0.17,0.223,0.193,0.303,0.263,"","","","",""]],[["",0.433,0.333,0.665,0.353,0.413,0.458,"","","","",""]],[["",0.355,0.3,0.263,0.258,0.355,0.215,"","","","",""]],[["",0.195,0.43,0.243,0.28,0.44,0.4,"","","","",""]],[[1.218,"","","","","","","","","","",""]]]}
```

Here is a screen shot of how it looks without setting the domain:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g68FI.png

Here is a screen shot of what it looks like when I do set the domain:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQEZC.png

Comment: could you set the domain to some ridiculously low but non-zero value, e.g. 0.00000000001? Or does your data legitimately include 0?

Comment: Some values can be 0, but I don't want those graphed either. I tried setting the empty values to -1 and the values don't show on the graph, but the spacing remains the same as if it had been graphed.

Comment: edited my post to include picture representation.

Comment: You would need to use an ordinal scale instead of a time scale.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a fiddle or equivalent, it's not possible to provide a copy-and-paste answer, but a general approach would be to remove the null values from the data before creating the chart.

Since the data in your example isn't formatted exactly as D3.js expects, I'll assume you're not simply fetching it using D3's built-in request function (e.g. `d3.json('url/to/data.json')`) but, rather, have the data in local variable. Assuming you also want to preserve the structure above, you could do something like the following. (It's not optimized to make the logic as clear as possible.)

```
var cleandata = {
    x_data: [],
    y_data: []
};
data.y_data.forEach(function(y_value, idx){
    if (y_value) {
        cleandata.x_data.push(data.x_data[idx]);
        cleandata.y_data.push(data.y_data[idx]);
    }
})
```

Comment: I have tried removing the empty values entirely, but that mucks up the date order on the x-axis: http://i.imgur.com/39PaZXi.png